# Does querying Azure AD (Entra ID) support case insensitive queries?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-entra-id

I am trying to locate accounts matching a certain phrase in my Azure Active Directory instance. The phrase needs to be case insensitive, however I am not finding a way to do that. All sorts of posts direct me to user 'lower' or 'tolower', which results in the error below.

> "Invalid jmespath query supplied for `--query`: Unknown function: lower()"

Here is what I currently have for a case sensitive search.

```
az ad user list --query "[?contains(displayName, 'Phrase')]"
```

This works great if I am trying to match 'Phrase', but fails on 'phrase', 'pHrAse', 'PHRASE', etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my tenant, I have 4 Entra ID users named **Sridemo** in different cases like this:

[image]

> Note that, Azure CLI does not support case-insensitive filtering **directly** using JMESPath expressions.

When I tried to retrieve these users by doing case insensitive search using `tolower()` method, I too got **same error**:

```bash
az ad user list --query "[?contains(tolower(displayName), 'sridemo')]"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below query that initially retrieves all users and filters them by display name converting to lower case:

```bash
az ad user list --output json | jq '[.[] | select(.displayName | ascii_downcase | contains("sridemo"))]
```

When I ran below script, I got **response** with expected details along with their **count** like this:

```bash
search_value="SriDemo"
search_lower=$(echo "$search_value" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

az ad user list --output json | jq --arg search "$search_lower" '[.[] | select(.displayName | ascii_downcase | contains($search))] | {count: length, users: .}'
```

**Response:**

[image]